# Kingston SSD with several bad blocks and zero reallocated sectors

Tags: ssd, bad-blocks

My Windows 8 installation was freezing randomly and I started to suspect my SSD drive.

After running HD Tune, I got a lot of damaged blocks, but S.M.A.R.T. shows zero reallocated sectors.

I thought SSDs would detect bad sectors and reallocate them automatically, isn't this true?

I'm using a KINGSTON SH100S3 with latest firmware.

[image: HD Tune Error Scan]

[image: SMART Report]

Kingstom Tools Report:

```
SMART READ DATA
    Revision: 10
    Attributes List
      1: (SSD Raw Read Error Rate)               Normalized Rate:  92  Sectors Read: 241812383 Read Errors: 378
      5: (SSD Retired Block Count)               Spare blocks remaining 100%  Retired Block 0
      9: (SSD Power-On Hours)                    Value 0  Total 2918 hrs 59 mins
     12: (SSD Power Cycle Count)                 Power Cycle Life Remaining 100%  Number of power cycles 679
    171: (SSD Program Fail Count)                Program Error Count 0
    172: (SSD Erase Fail Count)                  Erase Error Count 0
    174: (SSD Unexpected power loss count)       Unexpected power loss Count 89
    177: (Wear Range Delta)                      Wear Range Delta 1%
    181: (Program Fail Count)                    Program Error Count 0
    182: (Erase Fail Count)                      Erase Error Count 0
    187: (SSD Reported Uncorrectable Errors)     Normalized Value 0  lifetime URAISE Errors 30199
    194: (SSD Temperature Monitoring)            Normalized temp 33   Current 33  High 50 Low 16
    195: (SSD ECC On-the-fly Count)              Normalized Value 120   Sectors Read 241812383  UECC Count 0
    196: (SSD Reallocation Event Count)          Normalized Value 100   Reallocation Event Count 0
    201: (SSD Uncorrectable Soft Read Error Rate)Normalized Value 120  Sectors Read 241812383  Uncorrectable Soft Error Count 0
    204: (SSD Soft ECC Correction Rate (RAISE)   Normalized Value 120  Sectors Read 241812383  Soft ECC Correction Count 0
    230: (SSD Life Curve Status)                 Normalized Value 100
    231: (SSD Life Left)                         Life Remaining 100%
    233: (SSD Internal Reserved)                 2849
    234: (SSD Internal Reserved)                 2945
    241: (SSD Lifetime writes from host)         lifetime writes   2945
    242: (SSD Lifetime reads from host)          lifetime reads   3771
```

Is there a way to save this SSD? Why isn't it reallocating the sectors?

### UPDATE:

It's a notebook by the way. I removed the SSD and inserted it again just to make sure it was well plugged. The SSD is 9 months old.

I just ran chkdsk and got an interesting result:

```
X:\windows\system32>chkdsk.exe C: /F /R /X /B
The type of the file system is NTFS.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)...
  451328 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  7044 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)...
  623762 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered.

CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  86218 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  37225592 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Removing 3 clusters from the Bad Clusters File.

CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 34
of name \$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLogContainer00000000000000000002.
32 percent complete. (117050 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 117067
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Local\MICROS~1\SkyDrive\logs\SKD136~1.LOG.
33 percent complete. (171455 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 174285
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\USERDA~1\Default\History.
33 percent complete. (174269 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 175264
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Local\MICROS~1\Windows\TEMPOR~1\Content.IE5\R5MC6ID
I\POCOYO~1.JPG.
33 percent complete. (187752 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 188515
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\USERDA~1\Default\HIBAEA~1.
33 percent complete. (190030 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 190169
of name \PROGRA~3\MICROS~1\WINDOW~1\Scans\History\Results\Resource\{C10F4~1.
33 percent complete. (196692 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 196722
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\FILEZI~1\FILEZI~1.XML.
33 percent complete. (197855 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 198992
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\FILEZI~1\RECENT~1.XML.
33 percent complete. (198976 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 199028
of name \Windows\Prefetch\FILEZI~2.PF.
33 percent complete. (200204 of 451312 files processed)
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 200221
of name \Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\FILEZI~1\QUEUE~1.SQL.
  451312 files processed.
File data verification completed.

CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
  5325916 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
Adding 49 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

 117218303 KB total disk space.
  95199180 KB in 340440 files.
    192004 KB in 86219 indexes.
       196 KB in bad sectors.
    523255 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  21303668 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  29304575 total allocation units on disk.
   5325917 allocation units available on disk.
Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50.
```

I thought for a second that chkdsk fixed the problem but HD Tune still shows me the same damaged blocks. I will stress the notebook tomorrow to see if it still hangs randomly, but I have no hope :(

## Update 12/15/2013

Another example of a Kingston SSD with bad sectors, that the drive refuses to reallocate:

[image]

Comment: Could be something wrong with your SATA cable.

Comment: See my update, tks :)

Comment: Similar issue, except it's a single bad spot. Each scan it's the same single bad spot (e.g. not a bad cable). Zero reallocated sectors. The `pending sector count` is zero, meaning the drive doesn't even realize there is a bad sector that **needs** replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe SSDs are supposed to reallocate bad sectors. How old is the drive? Did you try updating firmware?

If the drive is fairly new (less than 2 yrs old), I suspect that the drive was faulty to begin with, and if possible maybe Kingston can replace it.

Cheers,
Leo

Comment: I'm using the latest firmware from Kingston. I don't think replacement is an option because I bought it in US and I live in Brazil. I've been using this drive for the past 9 months, the problem started 2 days ago. Too bad for me...

Answer (score 0):

Contact Kingston technical support regardless of where you live or buy equipment. I think you will get solution. They replied to me and we had a good conversation.